# Indexing a correlation matrix

Tags: r

I have two matrices tlike with the following example

## mat1

```
   row.names  geneid1  geneid2  geneid3  geneid4  geneid5
   sample1    0.99       8.76    8.78    7.65     5.4
   sample2    5.6        6.76    7.4     9.08     8.2
   sample4    7.5        6.4     6.4     6.1      8.6
```

## mat2

```
  row.names  geneid1  geneid2  geneid3  geneid4  geneid5
   sample1    0.98       8.76    8.78    4.65     5.4
   sample2    0.6        6.76    1.4     9.78     6.2
   sample4    9.5        9.4     3.4     5.1      8.0
```

in case I find the correlation between them and

```
      cormat<cor(mat1,mat2)
```

and the resultant matrix looks this way

```
            geneid1  geneid2  geneid3  geneid4  geneid5
   geneid1    0.1       0.14    0.58    0.89    0.5
   geneid2    0.6       -0.2    0.4     0.45    0.6
   geneid3    0.5        0.7    0.3    -0.4     0.76
   geneid4    0.65       0.64   0.76   0.45     0.7
   geneid5    0.3        0.2    0.6     0.2     0.2
```

I would like to select those values in the matrix which are above the threshold 0.5 and omit the rest of them.I want only the gene id numbers which are above that value rowise and columnwise. I tried using

```
         which(cormat>0.5)
```

but I do not understand how to index them with the original matrix and retain only those rows and columns which are above the value of 0.5. Is there some other way other than indexing that I could select highly correlated values for further analysis.

Comment: Do you care if it's negative or positive correlation? If both are interesting for your application you might want to use `which( abs(m) < 0.5, arr.ind=TRUE)` in @Hemmo answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use argument `arr.ind`:

```
which(cormat>0.5,arr.ind=TRUE)

set.seed(1)
m <- matrix(runif(9),3,3)
m
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.2655087 0.9082078 0.9446753
[2,] 0.3721239 0.2016819 0.6607978
[3,] 0.5728534 0.8983897 0.6291140
which(m < 0.5)
[1] 1 2 5
which(m < 0.5, arr.ind=TRUE)
     row col
[1,]   1   1
[2,]   2   1
[3,]   2   2
m[which(m < 0.5, arr.ind=TRUE)]
[1] 0.2655087 0.3721239 0.2016819
```